# Under what circumstances is it safe to release the python GIL?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11, gil

I have written a C++ library which runs machine learning inference. These inference functions generally use 8 threads each to optimize for low latency (though it can still take upwards of 100ms to complete the inference call). I have used synchronization primitives such as `std::mutex` to ensure the library is threadsafe.

I have also written python bindings for this library using [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11).

The current problem is that on a 16 core / thread CPU, it is optimal to run two inference function calls in parallel, thus utilizing all 16 available threads. This is fine in C++, but in python (with threading), due to the GIL, one inference call ends up holding the lock and the other cannot run in parallel. Note, I know I can solve this problem using multi processing, but I'd like to use threading instead due to the design of my library.

Can I therefore release the GIL when making the call to the C++ API function (in the [python binding layer](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/misc.html#global-interpreter-lock-gil)) since the C++ library implements the necessary thread safety? Are there any other considerations I need to make when releasing the GIL?

Answer (score 1):

The GIL protects every Python **object**.  If you aren’t accessing any, or it’s read-only access to an **immutable** object for which you have an owning reference, then it’s fine to release it.  Do be sure to keep an owning reference to anything you’ll use **after** reacquiring the lock, lest it have been destroyed while it was released.

Comment: The state of the object is mutable, however as mentioned I have implemented thread saftey for said object in C++. Is it therefore safe to release the GIL?

Comment: @cyrusbehr: If every access to the data is guarded by that C++ lock, it’s safe, although you’ll block Python from doing anything else (with other threads) unless all such calls also release the GIL.